# AS3 back button listener not working after task switching in Air for Android app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, admob, ane

Device BACK button in my as3 is prevented from default action and does other stuff instead (exits the app if main menu is currently displayed and returns to main menu if main menu is not displayed).

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent) { if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) { e.preventDefault();
// do stuff
} }
```

It works fine except in one case - when I click the AdMob banner (implemented through native extension) and then return from browser to app. Then the back button doesn't return to menu, instead it closes the app.

Weird thing is, back button stops working properly only when I return to app after clicking AdMob banner. If I click any other buttons that open the browser and then return to app, the back button works fine. It even works fine after I return to app after clicking the AdMob interstitial ad! So only AdMob banner breaks the back button.

I have tried to add back button listener again on Event.ACTIVATE (when user returns to app), but it didn't help.

What is happening and how can i prevent this? I wrote the admob native extension myself, so i can try to fix this issue both in as3 or android java. Thanks!

Comment: You need set focus on the stage first to get KeyBoardEvent.
stage.focus = stage; otherwise you'll miss it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe this is not the case. After I return to app, I keep using it (interacting with UI) and even then the keyboard BACK button exits app instead of going to main menu.
Another weird thing that when the app is exited this way, it is not seen in active apps list anymore, BUT when I start it again, it "resumes" as if it was still running in the background. I don't know what to think.